# how do I configure my testng IReporter to accept parameters

Tags: groovy, testng

IReporter is an interface that has a single `void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory)` method.  I would like to make the behavior of the reporter configurable so I can pass options to it when run on the commandline.  The documentation explains how to pass parameters to a reporter on the commandline:

> -reporter The extended configuration for a custom report listener.    Similar to the -listener option, except that it allows the
>   configuration of JavaBeans-style properties on the reporter instance. 
>   Example: -reporter
>   com.test.MyReporter:methodFilter=*insert*,enableFiltering=true  You
>   can have as many occurences of this option, one for each reporter that
>   needs to be added.

So it seems I should be able to call testng with `-reporter com.my.reporter:key1=value1,key2=value2`
but WHERE do I get the values passed in.

I've looked at the XMLReporter provided by testng, and it has a `private final XMLReporterConfig config = new XMLReporterConfig();` line, but I can't find out how the config is ever populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic, that's how it's done :-)  It appears it looks for instance variables on your class that implements IReporter with the same name.  It does need a stronger type than `Object` or `def` though it seems.  Here's an example.

```
class MyReporter implements IReporter {
    int foo; //<-- populated when instantiated

    @Override
    void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
        println "foo = ${foo}"
    }
}
```

And then to execute it:

```
testng ... -reporter 'full.path.to.MyReporter:foo=42'
```